# Relative path of audio file not working in ReactJS app

Tags: reactjs, audio

I have an audio player which plays songs from songsdata

AudioPlayer.js:

```
const AudioPlayer = () => {
  const [songs, setSongs] = useState(songsdata);
  const [currentSong, setCurrentSong] = useState(songsdata[0]);

  return (
  <div className="AudioPlayer">
      <audio src={currentSong.url} />
      <Player songs={songs} setSongs={setSongs} currentSong={currentSong} />
  </div>
  );
}
```

Audio.js:

```
exports.songsdata = [
{
    "title": "Song 1",
    "url": "../../assets/song1.mp3"
},
{
    "title": "Song 2",
    "url": "../../assets/song2.mp3"
}
]
```

What path should i give for the URL so that the audio player locates the audio files correctly?
I tried giving relative path "../../assets/" which is where the .mp3 files are relatively but I am getting a 404 error. I have used relative paths for images and videos and that worked but relative path for audio is not working. Also to mention, when i built the app, a static/media folder gets created which has the images and videos but not the audio files. Any particular reason for this?

Comment: Note that the paths should account to the file structure in the build, not in the source code.

Comment: Sounds correct. But does it vary for type of file? Like i mentioned i am using similar relative path for images and videos which works but not for audio files. I also edited the question with additional info. viz when i built the app, a static/media folder gets created which has the images and videos but not the audio files. Any particular reason for this? Thanks.

Comment: Well I don't know then. I guess it's something with your bundler's configuration, be it webpack or whatever bundler you're using